# My Navbar links are showing up under my navbar

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation, navbar

I am trying to get the Navbar links inside my navbar and they are showing up under it.  I am not sure what happened but I am using a flexbox because it is a requirement for the project I am working on but it moved my nav links and I am not sure why

```css
.mynav {
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 550px;
  background-color: #fbc616;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.navbar ul {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none; 
   font-size: 150%;
   font-family: RockSalt-Regular;
}
.navbar li {
    flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav pt-1">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I changed the font size to 100% and now it is in the navbar.  Is this the only solution?

Comment: Going over existing styles, removing them completely, or refining them is the right mindset for this type of problem. Feel free to check my suggestion for more clean up on the answer below.

Comment: It's not clear why you need `flex: 3`.

Comment: Ok, changed to flex 1 and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The magic of `flex` is that it scales to the size it needs, so usually hardcoding `height` and `width` are counter purpose to the usage of flex. removing the hardcoded height fixed the issue for me
[image]

```css
.mynav {
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 550px;
  background-color: #fbc616;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar ul {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none; 
   font-size: 150%;
   font-family: RockSalt-Regular;
}
.navbar li {
    flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav pt-1">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and for your tip above.  I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Marty sounds good, if you found this post helpful feel free to upvote or accept the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar ist simply cut off. I removed the `height` and now its showing correctly.

```css
.mynav {
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 550px;
  background-color: #fbc616;
  width: 100%;

}
.navbar ul {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none; 
   font-size: 150%;
   font-family: RockSalt-Regular;
}
.navbar li {
    flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mynav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav pt-1">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#work">Work</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, great.  That worked.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Marty sounds good, if you found this post helpful feel free to upvote or accept the answer. Cheers. –